# How can I replace values less than or equal to 0 with 1 in a 2d numpyarray?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I need to take the ratio of two image numpyarrays, and unfortunately the data has a bunch of negative values and zeros scattered about.

I found one elegant way to *remove* values from a numpyarray, `pixels = pixels[pixels>0]` (really elegant), but unfortunately doesn't replace values.

I also tried using a while loop, finding the current minimum value, and the current minimum index, assigning each to 1 until there is no value <=0, but it didn't work.

```
while(np.amin(pixels)<= 0):
     print "found low value of ", np.amin(evenpixels), "at", np.unravel_index(np.argmin(evenpixels), im_sz), "setting to 1"
     pixels[np.unravel_index(np.argmin(pixels), im_sz)] = 1
```

I got some weird behavior with this while loop and it is never able to exit the loop after trying to change the final low value to 1: it finds a 0 at (0,0) and get stuck here. I can't understand that and I wonder if it is an unrelated bug. Note that the shape of my data is `(2160, 2560)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the minimum value a pixel can be is 1 (positive integers), then a simple fix is to use `np.clip`, eg:

`pixels = np.clip(pixels, min, np.inf)`

where `min=1` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You are never changing the value of `pixel` in your loop, which is why you get stuck. But you actually do not need this loop, you can use numpy's built-in boolean indexing.

You can assign a replacing value where the value is below a threshold this way:

```
t = np.array([[0, 255], [-1, 128]]) # dummy (2, 2) image example
threshold = 0
substitute = 1
t[t <= threshold] = substitute
print t
```

will output

```
array([[  1, 255],
       [  1, 128]])
```

Edit: if you do not want to modify your array, but create a new one, you can do `new_array = np.maximum(1, t)` (I have assumed that your values are discrete, i.e. there are no values between 0 and 1).

Answer (score 1):

This is `numpy.where` key usage

```
np.where(pixels > 0,pixels,<ret value>)
```

or for instance:

```
np.where(pixels > 0, pixels / other_pxls, 0)
```

suit to your needs.